# How to create a dynamic Polygon

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I am trying to draw a polygon dynamically.I get the latitude and longitude from two different entities.Hence I concatenate them as below

```
var greenArr=new Array();
var point = new esri.geometry.Point(-85.91,25.68,this.parent.esriMap.spatialReference);  
var greenPolygon = new esri.geometry.Polygon(this.parent.esriMap.spatialReference); 
if (type == 'Green') 
{
var coords = '[' + parseFloat(longitude)+ ','+ parseFloat(latitude)+ ']'; 
greenArr += coords + ","; 
} 
greenArr="["+ greenArr +"]";
greenPolygon.addRing(greenArr); 
var result=greenPolygon.contains(point);
```

Here the contains method is not working.it returns false always

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the product from the ArcGIS platform that you are using, please?  It looks like ArcGIS API for JavaScript but I don't like to assume.